How to retrive ChoiceField value from a form?
I want to get the selected choice from a ChoiceField in a view. When I submit the form, I process it in a view:
views.py
def myFormSubmitView(request):

...
        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid form")
            post = Post()
            post.title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            post.body = form.cleaned_data["body"]

            **>>>>post.choice_test = form.cleaned_data["choice_test"]**

            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

I want to get the value of choice_test.
How can I do that ?
=========EDIT:========
This is the code of forms.py and models.py:
forms.py
from blog.models import Post
from django.forms import ModelForm

class NewBlogForm(ModelForm):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    section_ids =(
        ("1", "sec1"),
        ("2", "sec2"),)
    section = forms.ChoiceField(choices=section_ids)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/.../', error_messages = {'invalid':("Image files only")},)
    class Meta:
        model = Post 
        fields = ['title','section','body','image']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(xxx,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,upload_to='static/xyz')
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", related_name="posts")
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=False)
    shares = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Post() is a model not the request.POST.

Why are you constructing the Post manually, the ModelForm caan perfectly do that job.

The "Post()" in my code is the class name only, not the request.POST.

add forms.py code.

@ MohammedBaashar: yes I get that, but the form can make the Post itself, exactly such that you don't have to worry about converting the values.

There isn't any choice_test field in your form, perhaps you want to access the section field? Adding to that your model doesn't actually have a section field, are you sure you want that field in the form?

@AbdulAzizBarkat Apologies, I copied the code without focus.  Yes I meant the "section" field, the user should choose the section from a "CHOICEFIELD".

@MohammedBaashar: but your Post model has no section field either?

I might be wrong about this, but I think you can access the ChoiceField just like any other field by doing
form.cleaned_data["section"]

since "section" is the name of the ChoiceField.

The field returns an empty str, that's why I asked the original question.

try this, or you can include choice value in form.cleand_data with use forms.clean() method.
if form.is_valid():
  section = form.cleaned_data['section']
  choice = [i[1] for i in NewBlogForm.section_ids if i[0] == section][0]


the field returns an empty string.
